# Java MVC - Multiple Views - Single Controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm struggling here... I'm building a small calorie calculator application with Java swing using an MVC design pattern.

For some reason, the actionPerformed methods for my secondary view(SettingsView.java) don't do anything, yet for my main view(UserDetailsView.java) they work fine.

Here's my Controller class. (Simplified the code in the methods)

```
import com.willemdebruyn.macronutrientcalculator.model.Model;
import com.willemdebruyn.macronutrientcalculator.view.SettingsView;
import com.willemdebruyn.macronutrientcalculator.view.UserDetailsView;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


    public class Controller 
    {
        private UserDetailsView userDetailsView;
        private SettingsView settingsView;
        private Model model;
        private double requiredCalories;

        public Controller(UserDetailsView userDetailsView, SettingsView settingsView, Model model)
        {
            this.userDetailsView = userDetailsView;
            this.settingsView = settingsView;
            this.model = model;
            this.userDetailsView.addCalorieCalculationListener(new CalorieCalculationListener()); // Here I add the listeners for my main view, they work just fine
            this.userDetailsView.addMacroCalculationListener(new MacroCalculationListener());
            this.settingsView.addApplySettingsListener(new ApplySettingsListener()); // This is the one that doesn't work
        }

        class CalorieCalculationListener implements ActionListener
        {   
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("This prints...");
            }
        } 

        class MacroCalculationListener implements ActionListener
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("This prints as well...");

            }
        }

        class ApplySettingsListener implements ActionListener
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               System.out.println("This never prints...");

            } 
        }
    }
```

Here's the methods that add the ActionListener in my UserDetailsView, which work as expected

```
public void addCalorieCalculationListener(ActionListener listenForCalorieButton)
    {
        caloriesButton.addActionListener(listenForCalorieButton);
    }

    public void addMacroCalculationListener(ActionListener listenForMacroButton)
    {
        macrosButton.addActionListener(listenForMacroButton);
    }
```

Here is the code from my SettingsView to add the ActionListener (The one that doesn't work)

```
public void addApplySettingsListener(ActionListener listenForApplyButton)
{
     applyButton.addActionListener(listenForApplyButton);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Edit: 
As requested the SettingsView code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SettingsView extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    /**
     * Creates new form SettingsView
     */
    public SettingsView()
    {
        initComponents();
        myInit();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents()
    {

        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jInternalFrame2 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        metricRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        imperialRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        jInternalFrame3 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        carbsTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        proteinsTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        fatsTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        applyButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jInternalFrame2.setVisible(true);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Measuring System:");

        metricRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        metricRadioButton.setText("Metric (cm/kg)");
        metricRadioButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                metricRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        imperialRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        imperialRadioButton.setText("Imperial (in/lbs)");
        imperialRadioButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                imperialRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame2.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame2Layout);
        jInternalFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(imperialRadioButton)
                    .addComponent(metricRadioButton)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jInternalFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(metricRadioButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(imperialRadioButton)
                .addGap(0, 16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jInternalFrame3.setVisible(true);

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Carbs:");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Proteins:");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Fats:");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Custom Macros:");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Macro Nutrients Split:");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "<Carbs/Proteins/Fats>", "50/30/20", "80/10/10", "Custom" }));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame3.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame3.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame3Layout);
        jInternalFrame3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(110, 110, 110)
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(fatsTextField)
                                    .addComponent(proteinsTextField)
                                    .addComponent(carbsTextField))))
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addContainerGap(111, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jInternalFrame3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(carbsTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(proteinsTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(fatsTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(0, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        applyButton.setText("Apply");
        applyButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                applyButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame2)
                    .addComponent(jInternalFrame3)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(applyButton)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(applyButton)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void myInit()
    {
        // Metric radio button should be selected on default
        metricRadioButton.setSelected(true);

        // Disable textFields on startup
        carbsTextField.setEditable(false);
        proteinsTextField.setEditable(false);
        fatsTextField.setEditable(false);
    }
    private void metricRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                  
    {                                                      
        // When metric radio button is selected, deselect the imperial radio button
        imperialRadioButton.setSelected(false);
    }                                                 

    private void imperialRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                    
    {                                                        
        // When imperial radio button is selected, deselect the metric radio button
        metricRadioButton.setSelected(false);
    }                                                   

    private void applyButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                            
    {                                                
        System.out.println("Apply button clicked");
    }                                           

    public void addApplySettingsListener(ActionListener listenForApplyButton)
    {
        applyButton.addActionListener(listenForApplyButton);
    }

    public String getMeasuringSystem()
    {
        if (metricRadioButton.isSelected() && !imperialRadioButton.isSelected())
            return "Metric";

        else if (imperialRadioButton.isSelected() && !metricRadioButton.isSelected())
            return "Imperial";

        return "No Selection made";  
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton applyButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField carbsTextField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fatsTextField;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton imperialRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame2;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton metricRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField proteinsTextField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Edit 2: Here's my class containing the main method

```
import com.willemdebruyn.macronutrientcalculator.controller.Controller;
import com.willemdebruyn.macronutrientcalculator.model.Model;
import com.willemdebruyn.macronutrientcalculator.view.SettingsView;
import com.willemdebruyn.macronutrientcalculator.view.UserDetailsView;


public class App
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
         /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserDetailsView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserDetailsView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserDetailsView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(UserDetailsView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        UserDetailsView userDetailsView = new UserDetailsView();
        SettingsView settingsView = new SettingsView();
        Model model = new Model();
        Controller controller = new Controller(userDetailsView, settingsView, model);

        userDetailsView.setVisible(true); // SettingsView gets openend from this view
    }
}
```

Edit 3: UserDetailsView.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class UserDetailsView extends JFrame 
{
    private boolean calorieCalculationPerformed;

    public UserDetailsView() 
    {
        initComponents();
        myInit();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents()
    {
      // I removed the generated code, apparently my post exeeded the allowed limit
    }


    private void myInit()
    {
        // Disable macros button on startup, will enable again after caloric needs have been calculated
        macrosButton.setEnabled(false); 
    }
    private void maleRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                
    {                                                    
        // When male button is selected, deselect the female radio button
        femaleRadioButton.setSelected(false);
    }                                               

    private void femaleRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                  
    {                                                      
        // When female button is selected, deselect the male radio button
        maleRadioButton.setSelected(false); 
    }                                                 

    private void caloriesButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                               
    {                                                   
        calorieCalculationPerformed = true;

        System.out.println("Calories button gets clicked");

        if (heightField.getText().isEmpty() || weightField.getText().isEmpty() || ageField.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please fill in all the fields before performing the calculation.");  
            calorieCalculationPerformed = false;
        }
        else if ((!maleRadioButton.isSelected() && !femaleRadioButton.isSelected()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select your gender.");
            calorieCalculationPerformed = false;
        }
        else if (activityComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() == "<Select>")
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select your activity level.");
            calorieCalculationPerformed = false;
        }
        else if (goalComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() == "<Select>")
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select your fitness goal.");
            calorieCalculationPerformed = false;
        }

        // Only when caloric requirements have been calculated will the user be able to calculate macronutrient requirements
        if (calorieCalculationPerformed)
            macrosButton.setEnabled(true);
        else
            macrosButton.setEnabled(false);
    }                                              

    private void macrosButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                             
    {                                                 
        if (heightField.getText().isEmpty() || weightField.getText().isEmpty() || ageField.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please fill in all the fields before performing the calculation.");  
        }   
        else if ((!maleRadioButton.isSelected() && !femaleRadioButton.isSelected()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select your gender.");
        }
        else if (activityComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() == "<Select>")
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select your activity level.");
            calorieCalculationPerformed = false;
        }
        else if (goalComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString() == "<Select>")
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select your fitness goal.");
        }
    }                                            

    private void settingsButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                               
    {                                                   
         SettingsView settingsView = new SettingsView();
         settingsView.setVisible(true);
    }                                              

    public void addCalorieCalculationListener(ActionListener listenForCalorieButton)
    {
        caloriesButton.addActionListener(listenForCalorieButton);
    }

    public void addMacroCalculationListener(ActionListener listenForMacroButton)
    {
        macrosButton.addActionListener(listenForMacroButton);
    }

    public double getUserHeight()
    {
        if (!heightField.getText().isEmpty())
            return Double.parseDouble(heightField.getText());

        return 0.0;
    }

    public double getUserWeight()
    {
        if (!weightField.getText().isEmpty())
            return Double.parseDouble(weightField.getText());

        return 0.0;
    }

    public int getUserAge()
    {
        if (!ageField.getText().isEmpty())
            return Integer.parseInt(ageField.getText());

        return 0;
    }

    public String getUserGender()
    {
        if (femaleRadioButton.isSelected() && !maleRadioButton.isSelected()) 
        {
            return "female";
        }
        else if(maleRadioButton.isSelected() && !femaleRadioButton.isSelected())
        {
            return "male";
        }
        else return "No selection made";
    }

    public String getUserActivityLevel()
    {
        return (String) activityComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    }

    public String getUserGoal()
    {
        return (String) goalComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    }

    public void displayNutritionalInfo(String message)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message);
    }

    public void displayErrorMessage(String errorMessage)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, errorMessage);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> activityComboBox;
    private javax.swing.JTextField ageField;
    private javax.swing.JButton caloriesButton;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton femaleRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> goalComboBox;
    private javax.swing.JTextField heightField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JButton macrosButton;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton maleRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton settingsButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField weightField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of `SettingsView` ?

Comment: Sure, added it to the post, the majority of it is generated code though

Comment: I just added the following `main` method to `SettingsView` and it works well : http://pastebin.com/7DeXdc8K

Comment: Still doesn't explain why the action listeners in my controller only works for my main view, but thanks for taking the time to reply...

Comment: Nope I only create one instance in my App.java class (added to the OP as well)

Comment: I think we need the code of `UserDetailsView` too..

Comment: From the comment `// SettingsView gets openend from this view` , I suspect that `UserDetailsView` may create by itself an instance of `SettingsView`, instead of using the one you created in `main` .

Comment: Without a [mcve], youforces us to debug this for you. Did you try to clean this to only keep the components that failed ?

Comment: Added the UserDetailsView.java to the OP... Removed the generated code because I exceeded the limit.

Comment: _because I exceeded the limit_ That is one reason to create an example to reduce the length of the code and only focus on the problem.

Comment: As I suspected, `UsersDetailView` does a `SettingsView settingsView = new SettingsView();` , so the `SettingsView` displayed is not the one created in `main`, so not the one used by `Controller` .

Comment: Thanks Berger you were right all along, appreciate the help!

Comment: @AxelH Yeah my apologies, will keep in mind for future questions, still pretty new to this

Comment: @Will, I understand, this is why nobody has downvoted you. You will do better next time ;) Remember to focus on the problem, and show what is useful. This means a lot of code so this is better to create a new project with only what is necessary.